# Python (pygsheet): Expand variable for use as an index calling an array

Tags: python

```
import pygsheets
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
week = now.strftime("%V")

gc = pygsheets.authorize()
sht1 = gc.open_by_key('<secret key>')
wks = sht1.sheet1
```

```
values_mat = wks.get_values(start=(4,1), end=(57,4), returnas='matrix')
print(values_mat[week])
```

OR

```
row = wks.get_row(week)
print(row)
```

I'm looking to use the 'week' variable (at this current time is '32') for use to grab the 32nd row in a google sheet using pygsheet.

I have not been able to find a method to expand that 'week' variable for use as the index when calling an array value. Its interpreted as a string rather expanding the array value.

error output:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

EDIT:

More specifically, is it possible to use a variable to call an Nth variable in an array? ex. print(row[week]) where 'week' is a variable containing a number between 1 and 52.

EDIT:

I found the answer here. The variable I'm seeking to use to reference an index within an array must be declared as an integer.

```
week = int(week)
```

Comment: `datetime.strftime()` always returns a string. Have you tried just doing `week = int(now.strftime("%V"))`?

Comment: The code for datetime works fine, the problem comes in utilizing that variable stored in 'week' for use in printing the Nth variable in the values_mat or row array/list.

Comment: What is `wks` ? I don't see that object intialized